# 2004 Honda Civic clicking noise coming from dash

Tags: honda, noise, civic

I recently rebuild the engine with new head gasket head bolts and a bunch of other gaskets the car starts no problem doesn't overheat or anything however when I turn the key to accessory I get a clicking noise underneath the dash on the passenger side. What would cause such noise and why isn't affecting my car yet?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm in the process of changing out the head gasket on my 2003 Civic (D17A1 engine).

Comment: This is a new sounds since you finished your engine work? Can you isolate where under the dash? Can you hear it in the engine compartment, as well?

Comment: Is the fan for the heater/cooling system running? Can you change its speed to try to identify?